# simple program help - sending dynamic memory pointer to function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, operator-precedence

Ok, so I have a weird problem in my program and I don't really understand what is happening. The problem is:

- When I use only EXAMPLE 1, my program crashes
- And when I use EXAMPLE 2 it works

Can you explain to me why I can't use the first example?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int show(int **a, int *n){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<*n; i++){
        cout << "number is: " << *a[i] << endl; // EXAMPLE 1
        cout << "number is: " << *(*a+i) << endl; // EXAMPLE 2
    }
}

main() {
    int n = 3, i;
    int *a = new int[n];
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        cout << "number: ";
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    show(&a, &n);
}
```

Comment: first, you need an int before main

Comment: then, here is explanation, a is a pointer to a pointer to the first element of an array of 3 int. then you need to to get the pointer to the first element by deference it first

Comment: In the EXAMPLE 1, you dereference some pointer which isn't yours, undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator[]` has higher precedence than `operator*`, so `*a[i]` is same as `*(a[i])`. Note that `a` is a pointer to a *single* `int*`, so `*(a[1])` (deference on `a[1]`) will lead to UB.

You could use parentheses to specify the precedence what you want, change it to `(*a)[i]` then it would work well.

---

<sup>BTW1: You should declare return type for `main()`, like `int main() { ... }`.

BTW2:I'll suggest you to use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of raw array, since it's C++.</sup>

Comment: Also, given that this is C++ and your function isn't testing `a` isn't null, perhaps a reference is what's required?

Comment: @TobySpeight I'm not sure about OP's intent, I agree that passing by pointer doesn't make much sense here. In fact, for C++, the most preferable  way should be `int show(const std::vector<int>& a)`.